# Run many java applications via ssh in a bash script

Tags: java, bash, ssh

I'm trying to optimize some experiments with a Java application. The same application is on many machines. I want to run all of them via a bash script with ssh.

I have a bash script that has a `while` loop to run the application. Like this

```
while [ $COUNTER -lt $WORKERS ]
do
  ssh  ubuntu@host "java java-app.jar" > /data/some-logs.log 
  ((COUNTER++))
  ((IP_BEGINS++))
done
```

However when I run the script I have to wait a moment and press Ctrl+C for every machine. How can I run every aplication on background?

Comment: I'm a big fan of Fabric for remote execution: see https://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.12.1/usage/parallel.html

Comment: Thank you, I only need to use bash.

Comment: Read this https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-bash-commands-background-linux/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

prefix with `nohup` and append a `&` to the command, that will run it in the background.

```
while [ $COUNTER -lt $WORKERS ]
do
  ssh  ubuntu@host "nohup java -jar java-app.jar > /data/some-logs.log 2>&1 &"
  ((COUNTER++))
  ((IP_BEGINS++))
done
```

You might need to muck around with the quotes and placements of the `&` to make sure the remote ssh command gets backgrounded and not your local ssh

EDIT - I fixed the answer based on your comment. Also added the stderr redirect to the same log file, that might help when things go wrong

Comment: Thank you! It worked. However I had to change the prefix and & as you mentioned.
 ssh  ubuntu@host "nohup java java-app.jar  > /data/some-logs.log &"